# Android Camera Flashlight (Torch) is Not Available Due to Insufficient Resources

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I've tried a lot of methods to get flash working on Android camera.

Here is my code:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            try {
                final CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
                final String[] list = manager.getCameraIdList();
                manager.setTorchMode(list[0], true);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Flashlight Failed: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Flashlight Failed:
>   MAX_CAMERAS_IN_USE(5): setTorch-Mode:1882: Torch for camera "0" is not available due to insufficient resources

Screenshot of the error here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjgPU.jpg

Also, I checked my camera count and its only at 2, not 5 and I've tested on multiple phones and they all get this so its not the phone.

Comment: Try rebooting the phone. If the problem (temporarily) goes away, then you're somehow tying up a camera without releasing it. I don't know much of anything about `setTorchMode()`, though.

Comment: I tried, no luck :/

Comment: this happens when you are trying to flashing and camera open at the same time, dont open flash like this, use camera2 api and set it like requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE,CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);